# How to exclude viewmodel properties from CA1811

Tags: c#, mvvm, static-analysis

Using VS 2010/.Net 4.0, Code Analysis warning CA1811 (see below) is fired on all properties in a ViewModel even through they **are** used via XAML binding:

*Warning    CA1811 : Microsoft.Performance : 'BackupWindowViewModel.BackupCommand.get()' appears to have no upstream public or protected callers.*

```
public ICommand BackupCommand { get { return _backupCommand; } }  <--- CA1811

<Button Content="Backup" Command="{Binding BackupCommand}" />
```

This is because Code Analysis (currently) does not parse XAML.  My question is, is there a way to exclude **all properties in all ViewModels** (e.g. classes deriving from ViewModelBase) from CA1811?  Having to suppress this warning on each individual property is a huge pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open the project **Properties** page.
2. Click the **Build** property page.
3. In **Errors and warnings** section, modify the **Suppress Warnings** property: `/nowarn:1811`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f28x9z3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I never even noticed the 'Suppress Warnings' property.  So at least this can be done quite easily at a project level.  (Which means it may supress some valid warnings still.)  I guess we just have to wait for MS to include XAML parsing in Code Analysis to completely resolve this, so I'm marking this as answered for now, thanks.